# Please how do I perfectly create a relationship in power pivot between a date table (daily) and a Month table (Month)

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot

I have tried creating a relationship between my date table and Month table but I discovered that the Month table is interpreted as first day of the Month in the date table.

however, I tried creating relationship between the Month column on the date table and the month table but it power pivot does not support many to many relationship (my month table also contains other dataset)

I will really appreciate a solution to this problem

Thanks!

[image: This is what my date table looks like]

[image: This is the column I want to relate in my month table]

Comment: Create the relationship with the "Date" col in your date table. When using date slicers make sure to select the field from your date table.